# How to remove spaces in a character string at specific positions in R ?

Tags: regex, r, gsub

I have a long list of names and i have to count number of times each name has come up. However the names are mixed with spaces.

Here is the simple example

```
x <- c(" John D","John D ","John D")
table(x)
x
 John D  John D John D  
      1       1       1
```

You can see because of the spaces it is recognizing as three different names. What i have to do is without loosing the Space between John and D, I have to remove remaining spaces.
Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`gsub`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/grep.html) to remove the leading/trailing whitespace characters.

```
x <- c("   John D", "John D   ", " John D ")
y <- gsub('^\\s+|\\s+$', '', x)
table(y)
# y
# John D 
#      3
```

**Explanation**: `\s` matches whitespace (`\n`, `\r`, `\t`, `\f`, and `" "`) only at the beginning `^` and the end `$` of the string respectively. The `+` quantifier means match (**1** or more times).

You can also use the `stringr` library package.

```
library(stringr)
x <- c("   John D", "John D   ", " John D ")
y <- str_trim(x, side='both')
table(y)
# y
# John D 
#      3
```

Comment: can you please explain how it works ? so that i will learn instead of just copying your code

Comment: I think `sub` would also perform the same way, since we're only matching the first bunch of spaces on either end.

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
 library(stringr)
 x1 <- str_trim(x)
 table(x1)
 #x1
 # John D 
 #     3
```

Or

```
  gsub("^ +| +$", "",x)
 #[1] "John D" "John D" "John D"
```

- `^  +| +$` - 0 or more spaces either at beginning or end
- replace it with ""

if you have a vector like this:

```
x <- c("John     D", "   \n John D", "John  D \r")
library(qdap)
strip(x,lower.case=F)
#[1] "John D" "John D" "John D"
```

If there are no additional spaces between the names `str_trim` still works

```
 x <- c("  \nJohn D","John D\r ","John D")
 str_trim(x)
 #[1] "John D" "John D" "John D"
```

Comment: THanks @akrun i accepted the other answer because i got to learn something as well from that.